# sonar.projectbasedir not working in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have configured SonarRunner 2.3 in the Jenkins. In Execute SonarQube Scanner build process, I have updated my properties as

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=test
sonar.projectName=test
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.projectBaseDir=/opt/app/jenkins/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test1-BuildJob/workspace

#Path to Source
sonar.sources=/opt/app/jenkins/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-BuildJob/workspace/report-api/src, /opt/app/jenkins/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test1-BuildJob/workspace/test-dao/src, /opt/app/jenkins/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test1-BuildJob/workspace/test-model/src, /opt/app/jenkins/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-BuildJob/workspace/test-frontend/src
```

My jenkins job runs in different workspace.

> /opt/app/jenkins/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TestJob/jobs/test-SonarAnalysis

How do i configure sonar to run the analysis in given sonar.projectbasedir?

Comment: Why is the path in basedir different from the sourcedir (test-BuildJob  v.s.  test1-BuildJob)?

Comment: I have 2 jobs with custom workspace. One job is used for mave build. Another job is for sonar analysis. So I need to use the maven build workspace for sonar analysis